# CASE Statement in Where clause? Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to put CASE Statement in Where clause, but I am getting error: Incorrect syntax near '>'.

```
WHERE 
ItemCategoryID=@CategoryID 
AND AuctionStatus=1 
AND SE_UsersMain.isActive=1 
AND AuctionOwner!=@OwnerID
AND    
CASE                    
WHEN @CompareSign=1 THEN  @CurrentAmount>@FilterAmount 
WHEN @CompareSign=2 THEN @CurrentAmount<@FilterAmount 
WHEN @CompareSign=3 THEN @CurrentAmount=@FilterAmount 
END
```

Comment: what are you trying to acheive with this?

Comment: The query does not make much sense to me unless CurrentAmount is a column, not a parameter. Are you sure that's not a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE ItemCategoryID      = @CategoryID
AND AuctionStatus         = 1
AND SE_UsersMain.isActive = 1
AND AuctionOwner!         = @OwnerID
AND
    CASE
      WHEN @CompareSign  = 1 AND @CurrentAmount>@FilterAmount THEN '1'
      WHEN @CompareSign  = 2 AND @CurrentAmount<@FilterAmount THEN '1'
      WHEN @CompareSign  = 3 AND @CurrentAmount=@FilterAmount THEN '1'
      ELSE '0'
    END = '1'
```

Comment: Leaving off the apostrophes would be fine.  Then you would be dealing with integers rather than strings.

Comment: @user92546 do you expect that to make a big difference when dealing with single-character constants?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I expect it to make an enormous difference to coders from the land of C (and its derivatives) who will do _anything_ to save a character of source code.  Purists might choose to `CAST` the integers to `BIT` values, or use declared variables as the values.  As far as runtime performance, it would be a challenge to measure a difference so trivial.  I deeply appreciate your concern about my possible expectations.  Thank you very much for your inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

CASE is an expression that returns a single value, not a control of flow statement. Simplest way to implement this would probably be dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT ...';

SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE 
ItemCategoryID=$c$ 
AND AuctionStatus=1 
AND SE_UsersMain.isActive=1 
AND AuctionOwner!=$o$
AND $ca$ $sign$ $fa$;';

SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  '$c$', RTRIM(@CategoryID)),
  '$o$', RTRIM(@OwnerID)),
  '$ca$', RTRIM(@CurrentAmount)),
  '$sign$', CASE @CompareSign WHEN 1 THEN '>' WHEN 2 THEN '<' WHEN 3 THEN '=' END),
  '$fa$', RTRIM(@FilterAmount));

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a stored procedure the solution given by GavinCattell seems to be working but I think as you are not using any column in case statement then why are you doing this calculation inside query. You can use if-else statement for this.
Doing this inside query will slow down query to a great extent and using if-statement will be much faster.